# Hosts File Ignored but ping working well

Tags: networking, windows-10, ip, hosts, hosts-file

I recently changed the hosts file on a Mac and also a Windows 10 computer.

Both computers are used at home and at work.

My hosts file was supposed to redirect on specific url (abc.com) to a different IP. Both works fine in the office on both computers.

At home however both computers still connect to the old website.

Whenever I ping abc.com, I get the IP from the hosts file (which should be fine) but any browser would not show the desired URL.

I have already tried and reseted the router, however without success.

Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: Try flushing the DNS `ipconfig /flushdns` (On Windows, I'm sure there is a similar command for a Mac)

Comment: define "any browser" please?  which browsers specific?

Comment: I have tried ipconfig /flushdns on MAC and Windows.

Comment: I have tried Chrome (Windows & Mac), Firefox (Mac), and Safari (Mac). As this is perfectly working fine in the office I still feel it is the Router at home which might cause this? It's a Huawei HG8247H in case this helps.

Comment: did u find the solution?